# Iron Python Can Not find nltk_data

Tags: c#, python, .net, nltk, ironpython

So I am trying to call python defined in a python module I wrote from a C# project, naturally I am using C#'s ironpython facilities.

The issue is I am having problems with iron python when I use nltk. Everything imports fine. The issue is with nltk_data. It will not find the english tokenization model (punkt/english.pickle) when it calls tokenize. I tried everything, even adding the path to nltk_data to the searchpaths like so:

```
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

searchPaths.Add(@"C:\path\to\nltk_data");
searchPaths.Add(spackagesPath);
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

I'm fairly certain that's not what the searchpaths are used for and I did a similar thing on the python end with sys.append.path.

I figure this is an issue with iron python.
Before you say use nltk.download('punkt') or all, all the dependencies are in place (I know this because I can run as standalone python script). Also this question: [NLTK in IronPython from WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318335/nltk-in-ironpython-from-wpf) has nothing to do with my question except nltk. **I spent hours trying to fix this issue; I already saw this question and already am using the Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting library**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NLTK in IronPython from WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318335/nltk-in-ironpython-from-wpf)

Comment: already saw that bub. not my question bub.